# Show data like Pivot in Grid or any other control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, gridview

I want to show data like pivot grid. I am right now showing data like following. Please see following image or click on link.
http://screencast.com/t/CWeGy0vi
[image]

But I want above data like following:
http://screencast.com/t/ZTb2wk4cdmB
[image]

Any suggestion how to achieve this. Starting point. Should I use repeater?

Comment: How are you returning the data?  Do you want this done in SQL?

Comment: @bluefeet SQL is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your table structure, etc. it is hard to give an exact answer.  But I can suggest how you could perform this in SQL.  You have some previous questions tagged with sql server so I am guessing that.

You can do this using both an `UNPIVOT` and a `PIVOT`:

```
;with unpiv as
(
  select activity, 
      work, 
      Location+'_'+col as col, 
      value
    from
    (
      select activity,
        work,
        cast(AssignedTasks as varchar(50)) AssignedTasks,
        cast(CompletedTasks as varchar(50)) AchievedTasks,
        Location
      from yourtable
    ) src
    unpivot
    (
      value
      for col in (AssignedTasks, AchievedTasks)
    ) unpiv
),
piv as
(
  select Activity,
    work,
    London_AssignedTasks, 
    London_AchievedTasks,
    Geneva_AssignedTasks, 
    Geneva_AchievedTasks,
    row_number() over(partition by activity order by activity, work) rn
  from unpiv
  pivot
  (
    max(value)
    for col in (London_AssignedTasks, London_AchievedTasks,
                Geneva_AssignedTasks, Geneva_AchievedTasks)
  ) piv
)
select case when rn = 1 then activity else '' end activity,
  work,
  London_AssignedTasks, 
  London_AchievedTasks,
  Geneva_AssignedTasks, 
  Geneva_AchievedTasks
from piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e685/32).

The result is:

```
|   ACTIVITY |   WORK | LONDON_ASSIGNEDTASKS | LONDON_ACHIEVEDTASKS | GENEVA_ASSIGNEDTASKS | GENEVA_ACHIEVEDTASKS |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Activity 1 | Task 1 |                   10 |                    8 |                    1 |                    1 |
|            | Task 2 |                   15 |                   15 |                  100 |                   25 |
| Activity 2 | Task 1 |                    5 |                    5 |                    0 |                    0 |
|            | Task 2 |                    0 |                    0 |                    2 |                    2 |
| Activity 3 | Task 1 |                   10 |                   10 |                   50 |                   40 |
```

Edit #1, If you have an unknown or dynamic number of `Locations` then you can use dynamic SQL to return the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Location+'_'+t.tasks) 
                    from yourtable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'AssignedTasks' tasks
                      union all
                      select 'AchievedTasks'
                    ) t
                    group by location, tasks
                    order by location
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = ';with unpiv as
              (
                select activity, 
                    work, 
                    Location+''_''+col as col, 
                    value
                  from
                  (
                    select activity,
                      work,
                      cast(AssignedTasks as varchar(50)) AssignedTasks,
                      cast(CompletedTasks as varchar(50)) AchievedTasks,
                      Location
                    from yourtable
                  ) src
                  unpivot
                  (
                    value
                    for col in (AssignedTasks, AchievedTasks)
                  ) unpiv
              ),
              piv as
              (
                select Activity,
                  work,
                  row_number() over(partition by activity order by activity, work) rn,
                  '+@cols+'
                from unpiv
                pivot
                (
                  max(value)
                  for col in ('+@cols+')
                ) piv
              )
              select case when rn = 1 then activity else '''' end activity,
                work,
                '+@cols+'
              from piv'


execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e685/46)

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet, just one question can we make column headers with dynamic locations. Like in location there can be any location and as many locations. User can add as many locations as he wants to assign tasks so this should be dynamic. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @MuhammadKashifNadeem you can use dynamic SQL to generate the result, see my edit

Comment: Your profile tells that you are from Arizona and I was not expecting an answer at this time in the morning :) Thanks, let me check.